# Google Cloud FunctionsからGCSへCSVアップロードが出来ない

Tags: python3, google-cloud, google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud FunctionsからPub/Subを使用してGCSへCSVをアップロードしたいのですが、
プログラミング初心者で見よう見真似で作ったものの上手くアップロード出来ず詰まってしまいました。
引数が間違ってると思うのですが、ご指摘頂けないでしょうか・・・。
python3.7使用で、エンドポイントは「hello_pubsub」です。

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage as gcs

def hello_pubsub(self, df):
    project_id = "My First Project"
    bucket_name = "my_bucket"
    gcs_path = "/testbucket/foo.csv"

    client = gcs.Client(project_id)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)


    blob = bucket.blob(gcs_path)

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[5,6,7]],columns=["x","y","z"])
    blob.upload_from_string(df.to_csv)
```

Comment: 「上手くアップロード出来ず」は何か(エラーなど)メッセージ出てますか？アップロードしてるけどなにか違うものが上がってるとか？
もう少し状況を 質問に追記してみて下さい。
あと呼び出し側がないので, どこが間違ってるかなど指摘は難しいかも。
とりあえず気づいた点 … `to_csv` はメソッドなので `df.to_csv()` でしょう

Comment: 早急に反応頂き、有難うございます。()を足したらcsvファイル保存出来ました・・・！
呼び出し側はpub/subとcloud Schedulerを連携させていて、cloud Schedulerで実行を押すとpub/subのエンドポイントの関数が実行されるように作ってます。関数の中身で他にも処理を書きたくてテストのつもりで書いたのですが、関数は成功と出るのですが、ファイルが保存されずパッと見成功しているようにも見えないので質問した次第でした。初歩的な上に情報不足ですみません。